# Platform independent container for HTML5 which can send/receive data from socket

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

I have a GUI build in HTML5 and JavaScript.

Is there a container to run that HTML5 across all platform (Windows, Linux etc)?

I also need to send the data from JavaScript to the socket, at which an another server is listening. And I also need to use data from socket in my JavaScript code. `node-webkit` is good container but I don't know how to send/receive data on socket using it.

Answer (score 0):

Found few solutions, The Chromium Embedded Framework and Electron can be used along with websocket.